# A screenshot is automatically taken upon wakeup

Tags: gnome, gnome-screenshot

Each time I wake up my computer, gnome screenshot opens up and takes a screenshot.

I have no idea why that is and what I might have done to start this. But I would like to stop it and don't know how.

Comment: Have you checked the startup applications app to see if there is anything unusual in there?

Comment: it'S solved. i was in the keyboard shortcut section, accidentely clicked on take screenshot, and, as I thought the ocmputer was frozen, I closed and opened the computer, which then was aken as the new shortcut for the screenshot.

Comment: Okay, thanks for for the clarification. Please mark this question as solved.

Comment: how do I mark it as solved?

Comment: Click the checkmark next to your answer:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was in the keyboard shortcut section, accidentely clicked on take screenshot, and, as I thought the computer was frozen, I closed and opened the computer, which then was taken as the new shortcut for the screenshot

Comment: Hah you just discovered a new cool trick based in lid events!